# Is it possible to extract Firebase Authentication data from a program as an API?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication

everyone.

I have a question(trouble) with Authentication.

Is it possible to extract Firebase Authentication data from a program as an API?

For example, I would like to extract email address, Provider, Date, etc. from Python.

[image]

thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) documentation? It has a complete example that uses `list_users()` to fetch user from Firebase auth.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @Dharmaraj 

Comment: Thank you! I was able to successfully perform the extraction process I wanted to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the Firebase Admin SDK's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users), you can use `list_users()` to list users in pages of size 1000 each. Try the following example from the docs:

```
def list_all_users():
    page = auth.list_users()
    while page:
        for user in page.users:
            print('User: ' + user.uid)
        # Get next batch of users.
        page = page.get_next_page()

    for user in auth.list_users().iterate_all():
        print('User: ' + user.uid)
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to successfully perform the extraction process I wanted to do.